# How to select many rows from a dictionary (executemany select)

Tags: python, select, mysql, executemany

I'm using Python and its MySQLdb module, 
is it possible to do a "selectmany"-like from a tuple/dictionary/list in the condition

something like this:

```
cursor.executemany("""SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name= %(name)s""",[d.__dict__ for d in data])

selected_rows = cursor.fecthall()
```

doing a delete/update/insert works fine with this method :

```
cursor.executemany("""UPDATE customers SET item = %(item)s WHERE name = %(name)s""",[d.__dict__ for d in data])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the "WHERE IN" sql syntax, for example,

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name IN ('john', 'mary', 'jane');
```

Comment: What about at scale? Is batching queries the only solution?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used the `executemany` method yet, but I wonder if it's meant to be used for SELECTs. What about

```
... where name in (...)
```

instead of

```
... where name = ...
```

and inserting a tuple containing the keys of your `data` dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

`executemany` for the most part is for insertion or update. Doesn't really work well for querying [data](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#executemany), from my experience it will only return the last set of parameters.